# Is it possible to send SMS through the platform, using Marketing Cloud?

Tags: marketing-cloud, lightning-aura-components, api, sms

After a brief search on Google, I couldn't find many resources about this functionallity.

What I need is a Lightning Component that reads an account's contacts, and gives me the possibility to send an SMS to those who are selected in the component.

It is to my understanding that this specific component does not exist, so I would have to code it myself. But I'm more worried about the functionallity and the API around sending the message. Does it even exist? I ask this because in one of my previous searches I found some posts from 2013 that said the platform does not have this feature.

Comment: Is this what you're looking for? https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.noversion.mc-apis.meta/mc-apis/postMessageContactSend.htm

Comment: @JavierGarcíaManzano probably. I'll look into it in the next days. Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You would want to use [Marketing Cloud Connect](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=mc_co_marketing_cloud_connect.htm&type=5) for this.  Once you've installed and configured the package, there are a number of ways you can use Marketing Cloud's [Mobile Connect](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=mc_moc_mobileconnect.htm&type=5) product to deploy SMS message to your Sale Cloud leads and contacts.

Answer (score -1):

There are different salesforce app available on app exchange platform for SMS. You can look into [smsMagic](https://appexchange.salesforce.com/appxListingDetail?listingId=a0N300000024XvyEAE) app(Most popular app on salesforce platform) You can book a demo for SMS Magic on http://www.screen-magic.com. This app provides Lightning components which can be used. 
You can use app's api to send message if you want custom UI.

Comment: Not interested in external apps. Or should I say... my customer isn't interested in paying even more for this feature. :P

Comment: He says with Marketing Cloud in the title :)